# Can I get a localized language name for a locale code in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, localization

The `[NSSpellChecker availableLanguages]` method returns an array of locale codes (like "de", "en_GB" etc.). Is there a way that I can get localized language names (eg. "Deutsch" for "de" on a German system) from that on OS X in Objective-C?

(The spellchecker panel has a popup menu of these languages, so the OS obviously has a table.)

Comment: `-[NSLocale localizedStringForLanguageCode:]`

Comment: @Cy-4AH Thanks, post that as an answer and you'll get the credit.